# SQL syntax error when creating table if it doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXIST `users` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username` varchar(255' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
 `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 3):

EXISTS!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username varchar(255) NOT NULL, first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, email varchar(255) NOT NULL, password varchar(32) NOT NULL, sign_up_date date NOT NULL, activated enum('0','1') NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your sql:

```
 EXIST
```

should be

```
 EXISTS
```